# c# using other class method

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-methods

Thanks to NHMountainGoat for an answer!
Implementing Interface looks a good choice so we have only the 'needed' method instanciated. 
It looks like this now:
EDIT

```
class Machine
{
    //REM: MachineConnexion is a link to the main server where asking the data
    internal linkToPLC LinkToPLC;
    public IlinkToPLC ILinkPLC;
    public interface IlinkToPLC//Interface to linkPLC
    {
        Int16 MachineNumIS { get; set; }
    }
    internal class linkToPLC : IlinkToPLC
    {
        private Int16 Act_MachineNum;
        private List<string> genlnkPLCCanvas;
        private List<string> genlnkPLCworkingwith;
        static private List<string> ListSymbolNoExist;
        private string[] ListToPLClnk = {
                          "GlobalFolder.PMachine[{0}].",
                          "GlobalFolder.PMachine[{0}].STATE.",
                          "GlobalFolder.Machine[{0}].",
                          "GlobalFolder.Machine[{0}].STATE.",
                        };
        public linkToPLC()//ctor
        {
            genlnkPLCCanvas = new List<string>(ListToPLClnk);
            genlnkPLCworkingwith = new List<string>(ListToPLClnk);
            ListSymbolNoExist = new List<string>();
            Act_MachineNum = MachineNumIS;
        }
        public Int16 MachineNumIS { get { return (Int16)ReadWriteMachine("data"); } set { ReadWriteMachine("data", value); } }
        public string ValueExist(string ValueToreach, bool WorkingDATA = false)
        {
            if (!WorkingDATA)
            {
                for (int inc = 0; inc < genlnkPLCworkingwith.Count; inc++)
                {
                    string StrValueToReach = genlnkPLCworkingwith[inc] + ValueToreach;
                    if (MachineConnexion.SymbolExists(StrValueToReach))
                    {
                        ListSymbolNoExist.Clear();
                        return StrValueToReach;
                    }
                    else ListSymbolNoExist.Add(genlnkPLCworkingwith[inc] + ValueToreach);
                }
            }
            else if (WorkingDATA)
            {
                string StrValueToReach = genlnkPLCworkingwith[10] + ValueToreach;
                if (MachineConnexion.SymbolExists(StrValueToReach))
                {
                    ListSymbolNoExist.Clear();
                    return StrValueToReach;
                }
                else ListSymbolNoExist.Add(genlnkPLCworkingwith[10] + ValueToreach);
            }
            if (ListSymbolNoExist.Count != 0)
            {
                string ErrorList = "";
                for (int inc = 0; inc < ListSymbolNoExist.Count; inc++)
                {
                    ErrorList = string.Concat(ErrorList + "Num: " + inc.ToString() + " " + ListSymbolNoExist[inc].ToString() + "\n");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + ErrorList);
            }
            return null;
        }
        public object ReadWriteMachine(string VariableName, object DataToWrite = null, bool WorkingDATA = false)
        {
            string valueToFind = "";
            if (ValueExist(VariableName) != "FALSE")
            {
                if (DataToWrite != null) { MachineConnexion.WriteSymbol(valueToFind, DataToWrite); }
                return MachineConnexion.ReadSymbol(valueToFind);
            }
            return VariableName;
        }
    }
    public Machine()                  //constructor
    {
        LinkToPLC = new linkToPLC();
    }
}
```

And It doesn't work telling me that the reference object is not defined to an instance of the object..... in the line : Machine() LinkToPLC = new linkToPLC();//REM I found the bug, it was me ;o)) 24112016

//REM 24112016

What are the main differences between those two concept: static Instance and Interface?

Example:

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITestInterface InterInstance = new TestInterface();
        //test Interface
        bool value1 = true;
        value1 = InterInstance.invert(value1);
        InterInstance.print(value1);
        //test Instance static
        TestStaticInstance staticInstance = new TestStaticInstance();
        staticInstance.Instance.invert(value1);
        staticInstance.Instance.print(value1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class TestInterface : ITestInterface
{
    public bool invert(bool value)
    {
        return !value;
    }
    public void print(bool value)
    { 
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString()+"\n");
    }
    private void methodX()
    { }
}
interface ITestInterface
{
    bool invert(bool value);
    void print(bool value);
}
public class TestStaticInstance
{
    public TestStaticInstance Instance;
    public TestStaticInstance()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    internal bool invert(bool value)
    {
        return !value;
    }
    internal void print(bool value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't think of inheritance just as a tool for code reuse.  There are many ways to do that - composition, utility classes, static methods, etc.  Inheritance implies an "is-a" relationship - if `otherstuff` _is a_ `linktoPLC` then inheritance may be appropriate.  If it just _contains a_ or _needs a_ PLC then composition may be the right choice.

Comment: There are no _copies_ - each instance of `linktoPLC`, including `needanotherone`, has its own `genlnkPLCworkingwith` collection. Consider a base class `Animal` with a `List<Flea> fleas` collection - each `Dog` and each `Cat` would have their own collection of fleas, and `myDog.Scratch()` can only remove fleas from his collection. Making it static _would_ cause the collection to only exist once - but I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Reading your question again I'm confused - are you asking if `needanotherone` and `LinkToPLC` share the list referenced by `genlnkPLCworkingwith`?  The answer to that is no.  Since you ask about `virtual` and `override` I'm not sure what you're trying to do - `virtual` and `override` are applicable to _methods_, not _data_.

Comment: Note that this would be legal and you would be referencing the same list through weach varaible:  `linktoPLC LinkToPLC = new linktoPLC(); otherstuff needanotherone = LinktoPLC;`

Comment: If you don't want to make changes in copy instead you want to change the main variable(list) just make that variable as static so it will not allow to create a new copy to any instance.

Comment: You have edited too much of the answer into the question. The first line should not read _Thanks to NN for the answer. [...] It looks like this now_. It is better to leave the question as a question, possibly edited with clarification on what is being asked. The solution should go in dedicated answer post (below these comments).

Comment: Hello, How can I rewind to my previous post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you structure your other classes to take an instance of the link class?  See:

```
/// <summary>
/// just a stub to demonstrate the model
/// </summary>
internal class Machine
{
    public string ReadData() { return "this is data"; }
    public void WriteData(string data) { Console.WriteLine(data); }
}

internal interface IMachineDataAccessor
{
    string Read();
    void Write(string data);
}

class LinkClass : IMachineDataAccessor
{
    protected Machine _machine;

    public LinkClass(Machine machine)
    {
        _machine = machine;
    }

    public void DoMyWork()
    {
        // insert work somewhere in here.

        string dataFromMachine = Read();

        Write("outbound data");
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        return _machine.ReadData();
    }

    public void Write(string data)
    {
        _machine.WriteData(data);
    }
}

class PersistentClass
{
    IMachineDataAccessor _machineImpl;

    public PersistentClass(IMachineDataAccessor machineAccessImplementation) 
    {
        _machineImpl = machineAccessImplementation;
    }

    public void DoMyWork()
    {
        string dataFromMachine = _machineImpl.Read();

        // insert work here.  Or anywhere, actually..

        _machineImpl.Write("outbound data");
    }
}

class StateClass
{
    IMachineDataAccessor _machineImpl;

    public StateClass(IMachineDataAccessor machineAccessImplementation) 
    {
        _machineImpl = machineAccessImplementation;
    }

    public void DoMyWork()
    {
        string dataFromMachine = _machineImpl.Read();

        // insert work here.  Or anywhere, actually..

        _machineImpl.Write("outbound data");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LinkClass link = new LinkClass(new Machine());
    PersistentClass persistent = new PersistentClass(link as IMachineDataAccessor);
    StateClass state = new StateClass(link as IMachineDataAccessor);

    persistent.DoMyWork();
    state.DoMyWork();
    link.DoMyWork();
}
```

Comment: Jablonovo, can you mark my response as the answer?  I need the reputation points.  Also, I definitely expected you to restructure the code -  but I see that you are creating new instances of LinkClass within Persistence and State classes - I thought it was important to keep it down to one instance - if so, then I would go back to taking a reference in the constructor.  This way, only one instance can be created and shared.  Are you clear on the differences between a class and an instance?

Comment: Done. I guess I'm clear, a class is like a canvas of object and an instance is the object rising from the floor and guetting a soul, a name and some things it can do or not. As linkclass is part of the machine I needed to have access to it but not to all so I had the rest protected from doing anything with it. Does these interfaces instances implement only the method I put in the interface? Or is it instanciating the whole thing but let an access only to the method referenced? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your second question is correct - The whole class is instantiated, but only the interface (the methods of the interface) are made available to your other consumers.  Interfaces offer great benefits far beyond this use..BTW.